# Why are CSS declarations for about:addons placed in userContent and not userChrome, given that the namespace is XUL?

Tags: css, firefox, customization, xul

Why do CSS declarations for `about:addons` have to be placed in `userContent` and not `userChrome`, given that the namespace of `about:addons` is **XUL**?

This is regarding CSS programming for Firefox.

*Related: [What namespace should be defined in Firefox's userContent.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807995/what-namespace-should-be-defined-in-firefoxs-usercontent-css)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to this is that the page `about:addons` is considered content. Thus, *userContent.css* is used. The namespace(s) (e.g. HTML, XUL) of the elements used in the `<document>` don't matter with respect to which of *userChrome.css* or *userContent.css* is used (only one or the other is used per `<document>`).

What does matter is the role for which the `<document>` is being used.  If the `<document>` is being used for chrome, *userChrome.css* is used. If it's being used for anything else, it's considered content for which *userContent.css* is used.

If it's something that's displayed in the content area of Firefox by navigating to the page (e.g. by changing the entry in the [URL bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bar)), then it's content, even if it's using XUL elements.

[MDN defines "chrome" as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome):

> In a browser, the chrome is any visible aspect of a browser aside from the webpages themselves (e.g., toolbars, menu bar, tabs). This should not to be confused with the Google Chrome browser.

It also provides a link to a blog post, "[Browser and GUI Chrome](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/browser-and-gui-chrome/)", which provides a similar definition:

> Chrome is the visual design elements that give users information about or commands to operate on the screen's content (as opposed to being part of that content). These design elements are provided by the underlying system — whether it be an operating system, a website, or an application — and surround the user's data.

In Firefox, the **content** portion of the display is:
[image: Firefox content flashing]

The **chrome** portion includes everything else.  This includes interface popups (e.g. the add bookmarks dialog), but not content-page popups. While it also includes the borders around the window, many people generally think of it including this portion of the display:

[image: Firefox chrome flashing]

### More detail

Specifically, only one of *userChrome.css* or *userContent.css* is applied to each `<document>`.  It is done [in this code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/720b5d2c84d5b253d4dfde4897e13384dc97a46a/layout/base/nsDocumentViewer.cpp#2207).  The choice in the code comes down to what value is of the property `document.docShell.itemType`. If that value is a 0, then *userChrome.css* is used, if not (or does not exist, etc.) then *userContent.css* is used.

The `itemType` can have the following values:

- typeChrome = 0,
- typeContent = 1,
- typeContentWrapper = 2,
- typeChromeWrapper = 3,
- typeAll = 2147483647

Which is assigned depends on how the page/file is loaded, not just the type of file, or the URL.  For instance, an *.xul* file which is loaded from a `chrome://` URL may be contained in a `typeContent` `<document>` (has *userContent.css* applied), if it was loaded from the URLbar. On the other hand, the same *.xul* file which is loaded as the content for a `<window>` with `openDialog()` may be in a `typeChrome` document (has *userChrome.css* applied).

The namespace of the elements contained in the file used for the  doesn't matter to which of the two files, *userChrome.css* or *userContent.css*, is used. The namespace does matter for if the CSS applies to the elements (at least if it is a `typeChrome` `<document>`).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer Makyen!  I thought they also defined anything completely within the **XUL** namespace as *chrome*.  For example, http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome-example.css shows that defining the namespace as XUL is required for declarations affecting other chrome elements.  So why not for declarations affecting the elements within `about:addons`, given that it's within the **XUL** namespace?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, I added a bit more detail to this answer. In short, only one, never both, of the two files is used per `<document>`. The namespace of the elements contained in the file used for the `<document>` doesn't matter to which of the two is used. The namespace does matter for if the CSS applies to the elements (at least if it is a `typeChrome` `<document>`).